# In C11, string literals as char[], unsigned char[], char* and unsigned char*

Tags: c, string-literals, unsigned-char

Usually string literals is type of const char[]. But when I treat it as other type I got strange result.

```
unsigned char *a = "\355\1\23";
```

With this compiler throw warning saying "pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness", which is quite reasonable since sign information can be discarded.

But with following

```
unsigned char b[] = "\355\1\23";
```

There's no warning at all. I think there should be a warning for the same reason above. How can this be possible?

FYI, I use GCC version 4.8.4.

Comment: When asking questions about C, always include the C tag or people won't find the question. You shouldn't use the C11 tag unless your question is about C11-related features. If so, combine the C and C11 tags. I've fixed the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of string literals in C is `char[]`, which decays to `char*`. Note that C is different from C++, where they are of type `const char[]`.

In the first example, you try to assign a `char*` to an `unsigned char*`. These are not compatible types, so you get a compiler diagnostic message.

In the second example, the following applies, C11 6.7.9/14:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
>   literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
>   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

Meaning that the code is identical to this:

```
unsigned char b[] = 
{ 
  '\355',
  '\1',
  '\23',
  '\0'
};
```

This may yield warnings too, but is valid code. C has lax type safety when it comes to assignment<sup>1</sup> between different integer types, but much stricter when it comes to assignment between pointer types.

For the same reason as we can write `unsigned int x=1;` instead of `unsigned int x=1u;`.

As a side note, I have no idea what you wish to achieve with an octal escape sequence of value 355. Perhaps you meant to write `"\35" "5\1\23"`?

---

<sup>1</sup> The type rules of initialization are the same as for assignment. 6.5.16.1 "Simple assignment" applies.

Comment: I wanted to handle byte stream of the RAW image. In original code I used \377.

Comment: `char[]` is not actually a type, so this is incorrect. See sec 6.2.5 "Types" of the c99 or c11 standards, which says "An array type of unknown size is an incomplete type". If you look at what sec 6.4.5 "String literals" actually says, it says that each string literal is "an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain [the sequence]" – i.e., it will be of type `char[10]`, or `char[11]`, etc. depending on how big the literal is.

Answer (score 2):

The first is the initialization of a pointer, the target types of pointers must agree on signedness.

The second is the initialization of an array. The special rules for initialization with string literals have it that the *value* of each character of the literal is taken to initialize the individual elements of the array.

BTW, other than you state, string literals are not `const` qualified in C. You don't have the right to modify them, but this is not reflected in the type.